# CSS not loading in AngularJS templates

Tags: web

I am currently designing a website, using HTML, CSS and AngularJS. I currently have the templates loading perfectly into the index depending on what the link is - however the CSS does not work for each template file.

For example, the index file is where the template is loaded in to. The index file's CSS works perfectly, however the CSS for the template that was loaded in does not. So half of the page has CSS loaded and the template half does not.

Is there a way around this, or to make the CSS load for both the index and template? Here is some code if you need it:

Index: http://pastebin.com/UzTb40Np
Template: http://pastebin.com/TtTJj5T8

I would post the CSS and AngularJS however I cannot post more than two links. It is a standard set up though, and the CSS has been validated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would recommend that you include all your css files in the index.

However it seems your template starts with a html tag, this is probably not correct. The content from your template will be included under the div bearing the ng-view directive.

You should have a better look at [this section of the angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), as well as the docs for [the ngView directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)